# Python Regular Expression find repeating digits

Tags: python, regex, repeat, digit

I have a Python question imagine variable x below. I want to write a regular expression that helps me finds any repeating single digits. Like 1 is not repeated, but 2 is mentioned twice, and 3 is 3 times.

```
x='1234328732'#a string of digits

re.search(r'(\d+).*\1', x).group(1)
```

this is what I thought, but this just gives me a return of patterns. The above returns nothing cause there is no repeating patterns. But if

```
x='1231231234'
```

it will return 123
But repeating patterns is not what I want. I want repeating digits. So for the first x it should give 2, 3
for the second x it should give 1, 2, 3

This is for learning the RE idea mostly
Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

may be something like this, using `Counter()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> x='1234328732'
>>> c=Counter(re.findall(r'\d',x))
>>> [x for x in c if c[x]>1]
['3', '2']


>>> x='1231231234' 
>>> c=Counter(re.findall(r'\d',x))
>>> [x for x in c if c[x]>1]
['1', '3', '2']
```

Comment: You can get rid of the regex completely: `Counter(x)`.

Comment: Yes but the OP wanted to use a regex.

Comment: @Blender Yes I can, but what if the string has other characters too.

Comment: This does do the job but can you please explain what it is actually doing?

Comment: @StudentOfScience Counter returns an dictionary, in which keys are the unique elements of the sequence passed to it, and values are count of that key in that sequence. so for second `x`, Counter is something like `Counter({'1': 3, '3': 3, '2': 3, '4': 1})`, and you can iterate through this dictionary to find values >1.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary if the string has other characters then you could avoid the regex by using `c=Counter(x)` followed by `[x for x in c if x.isdigit() and c[x]>1]`